# Confusion with JSON_DECODE second param

Tags: php, arrays, json

I just created a small program to check JSON and JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

```
$tree =  [
    0 => array
    (
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => '0',
        'name' => 'b',
        'surname' => 'myfolder/b'
    ),

    1 => array
    (
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'ignore',
        'surname' => 'myfolder/ignore2'
    ),

    2 => array
    (
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'ignore2',
        'surname' => 'myfolder/ignore4'
    )

];
var_dump($tree);
$try = json_encode($tree);//To print with key. Also if we decode we get result as object
//echo $try;
echo '<br />';
$try2 = json_decode($try,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
var_dump($try2);
```

$try2 is exactly equal to $tree an associative array.
Whereas if I remove `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` from this line

```
$try2 = json_decode($try,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I get an array with child object. Though `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is supposed to be used with json_encode but using it with json_decode, I get a surprising result. I am unable to understand whats going on inside?? I thought when I encode it and decode it I should get same result. But I got the same result only when I used `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`. Can anyone please help why this happens?

Comment: According to the manual, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) accepts `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` while [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) does not.

Comment: `json_decode` has no options flag. The second parameter is boolean. `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is only an option for `json_encode``

Comment: @nik I didnt get your point. JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is not boolean. How can it accept that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

`json_decode` returns an array of `objects` if you want to convert them in `assoc array` you should specify the second param which is a `boolean`

`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is an `int` with value `16`...
when this is passed as second param `php` cast/converts it to its bool equivalent which `true`.

To test the above stated behavior try:

```
var_dump((bool)1; (bool)2, (bool)16) 
//output  bool(true)  bool(true)  bool(true) . 
var_dump((bool)0)
//outputs bool(false)
```

So it's nothing to do with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`...even

```
json_decode($try,true);
json_decode($try,2);
json_decode($try,3);
json_decode($try,4);
json_decode($try,'someVar');
....
//should return your expected result (assoc array)
```

Similarly if you pass `0` as second param PHP will cast it into `bool` (which is `false`) and returns you an `object`

```
json_decode($try,0);
json_decode($try,false); 
json_decode($try,null)
json_decode($try)
...
//will return objects
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. My confusion is cleared now.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `json_decode` is a boolean. It accepts `true` or `false`. It does not accept `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`. You're trying to use the wrong constant for the wrong function.

`json_decode`'s *4th* parameter accepts a bitmask of constants, but currently it only supports `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`.

If you want to return `stdClass` instances for JSON objects from `json_decode`, set its second parameter to `false` (the default). Setting it to any non-falsey value makes it return associative arrays instead of objects. Setting it to `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` counts as "not-falsey".

It's all described in the manual: http://php.net/json_decode